# WebSphere Mobile Version

Tags: websphere-portal

I have heard I need Mobile Portal Accelerator for the creating Mobile version of existing IBM WebSphere portal. Is it free of charge? How can I find the distributive?
Are there any other ways to create mobile version of the website?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create mobile versions of your site. Example of possible ways are:

- Coding from scratch (time consuming)
- What you suggested ([Mobile Portal Accelerator](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Mobile%20Portal%20Accelerator%208%20Product%20Documentation#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=prodDoc))
- [IBM WebSphere Portal Mobile Experience](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Fast%20Track%20Documentation%20for%20Version%208#action=openDocument&res_title=IBM_WebSphere_Portal_Mobile_Experience_V8&content=pdcontent)